# HTML CSS Jquery ,Muliple Valued text Input as tags of a Product

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a product and want to assign tags to product, so i don;t know how to get multiple value text in one input,
i need same as in Stack over flow has during ask question tags option

Comment: The native browser input element is not allowing multiple values, to do some you have to demonstrate input value in other HTML tags and save them BTS in input value, you can use some plugins to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple check this.You can add multiple tags with this. Hope helps :)

Answer (score 0):

One tag have different value in html5. you will do define random data value.
Example:

```
  <div name="product1" data_value1="product property1"  data_value2="product property2"></div>
```